# How to convert String to Page name

Tags: asp.net

Hi all I am getting all the pages in an application, now I would like to traverse to each page, and convert it to page type I have written the following code which is not working can some one help me

```
string pageName="WebFomr1.aspx";
System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                            Type t_form = asm.GetType(asm.GetName().Name + "." + pageName);
                            Page p = Activator.CreateInstance(t_form) as Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a *.aspx as a class instance, but **you should see that a Page must have a code-behind page** (e.g: WebForm1.cs file and design one). So that's a class. And you should try something like that:

```
**string pageName="WebForm1";**
System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type t_form = asm.GetType(asm.GetName().Name + "." + pageName);
Page p = Activator.CreateInstance(t_form) as Page;
```

Comment: Hi it is working but I am unable to find the controls

Comment: You can use "FindControl" to find out the specific control you wanna search for.

Comment: But the p.Control is giving `0`

Comment: Can you add your aspx codes for us to see by editing your original thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use class name instead of page name,so `string className="WebForm"`.
And pay attention to `asm.GetType()`method:concatenate the right string "the namespace of the class + the class name"